# remove from collection without load all collection data. confused which collection mapping to use

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a many-to-many relationship between Assignment and User

When trying to delete an user from an assignment, I see all users are loaded in the collection.

How to I avoid that?

```
public class User
{
  public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
  public virtual IList<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }
}


public class Assignment
{
   public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
   public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
HasManyToMany(user => user.Assignments).Table("UserToAssignment").ParentKeyColumn("UserId").ChildKeyColumn("AssignmentId").Inverse().ExtraLazyLoad();  

HasManyToMany(productAssignment => productAssignment.Users).AsSet().Table("UserToAssignment").ParentKeyColumn("AssignmentId").ChildKeyColumn("UserId").LazyLoad();
```

Calling code:

```
assignment.Users.Remove(user)
```

Initially I used Bag instead of Set for Assignment mapping, but when updating it, it was deleting and then reinserting alot of rows in the AssignmentsToUsers table. So I changed to using Set.

But now I see a problem with using Set: it brings all data in memory.

What is the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid this and I would ignore it if performance is acceptable. If performance is a problem, there are three ways I can think of to tackle it:

1. If the other side of the collection (User.Assignments) is lighter weight then remove the assignment from the user instead.
2. Model the many-to-many table and delete the object directly. You would have to be certain that the Users collection is not going to be loaded prior to this because the in-memory representation will still contain the deleted record.
3. Direct delete using SQL -- this has the same caveat as #2.

Answer (score 0):

You should use extra lazy mode also for Assignment.Users.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Please correct me, but I read that Set needs data in memory in order to actually insert a new item. This is because the Add method on the collection class returns a value. So that's how Set actually works.

Comment: Yes, it might be that extra-lazy only works for indexed collections (list and map), but I'm not sure.

Comment: I am a bit disappointed that I didn't get any conclusive answer.